# Can not get out from loop using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue. I need to out from inner loop once DB will be updated using PHP but in my case its not happening like this. I am explaining my code below.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
     for ($j=0; $j < 4; $j++) { 
         $index=$j+1;
          $up_sql=" file".$index."='".$result[$i]['img']."' ";
         $sqlget=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from cn_sell_info where file".$index."= '' and sid =".$sid);
         if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlget) > 0){
              $update="update cn_sell_info set  ".$up_sql." where sid=".$sid ;
              $upsql2=mysqli_query($connect,$update);
               break;
          }
   }
}
```

Here I have put `break` statement still same value is updated in cosucative columns as per code. I need once table will updated it will come out from inner `for loop` means again `first for loop` will execute again.Please help me.

Comment: is your code entering the if statement?

Comment: yes, The code entering the if statement as per condition true. But here I need once update will finish it will come out from 2nd for loop and first for loop will again iterate.

Comment: instead of break put $j=4

Comment: I guess you want your program to carry on after the body of the *outer* `for` loop when you perform the SQL `update` statement. Is that correct?

Comment: `break 2` exists from the top loop. But you should really re-assess that code. It's horrible. Beyond description.

Answer (score 1):

Break has an optional parameter which indicates the number of levels to break out of. so `break` is equivalent to `break 1`.  But you can do `break 2` which breaks out of two levels of nesting.

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Above is from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php which gives good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `break`, you can use `while` loops with natural exit conditions. You don't need to calculate `$up_sql` every time, do it once inside the `if` (it's included in query below).

```
$num_rows = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($result) && !$num_rows) {
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < 4 && !$num_rows) {
        $index = $j + 1;
        $sqlget = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from cn_sell_info where file{$index} = '' and sid = {$sid}");
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sqlget)
        if ($num_rows) {
            $update = "update cn_sell_info set file{$index}='{$result[$i]['img']}' where sid={$sid}";
            $upsql2 = mysqli_query($connect, $update);
        }
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```